# Some of rewrite rules are not working (.htaccess)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^admin/api/(.*)$ admin/api.php?method=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin/index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)/$ api.php?method=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpg|png|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [QSA,L]
```

I want separate API entry point for admin module, but rewrite does not work as I want. What's wrong with rewrite rules?

host.com/page - works (/index.php),

host.com/admin/page - works (/admin/index.php),

host.com/admin/api/section - executes /index.php (but expected /admin/api.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your rules are looping as `admin/.*` pattern also matches `admin/api.php`. Have rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^admin/api/([^.]+)$ admin/api.php?method=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^admin/([^.]+)$ admin/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^api/([^.]+)/$ api.php?method=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpg|png|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
```

Comment: This solution works! Can you explain please why it doesn't stop on first match with L flag?

Comment: `L` doesn't all the rules it just forces `mod_rewrite` to execute again from start. It is like a `continue` of a `while` loop.